How to determine an overlapping sequence of words between two texts
In one of our digital assignments, I had asked my students to read an article and write a few things they learned from that article.  Students were told that they were supposed to write using their own words.  I also had reasons to expect that copying and pasting a block of text or all of it was disabled.  But I was so wrong.  I received over 9000 entries of texts where many of them looked like they were copied and pasted directly from the digital assignments. Some had some differences in punctuations and capitalizations but I cannot imagine that they literally sat there and typed most of the article out.
I have read through many of the students' assignments and tried to identify unique features from a copied and pasted entry versus an honest one so that hopefully some R function would help me to detect.  However, I have not been successful. To demonstrate, here is an example that I made up. The passages are often long, between 300-800 words and I wonder if there's a relatively easy way to identify the common block of words that overlap between the two texts.
text_1 <- "She grew up in the United States. Her father was..."
text_2 <- "I learned that she grew up in the united states.Her father was ..."

Desired Outcome: "she grew up in the united states. Her father was ..."
The desired outcome should print the sequence of words that overlapped between the two vectors, and capitalization or space differences do not matter
Thank you for reading and for any expertise you can share.

My first thing to try would be to set to lower case, then look at ngram tokens (ie strings of n contiguous words) to identify how many phrases of 5 / 10 / 20 words are identical. https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams

You could extract "blocks" that are the same, but the term block is ambiguous. For example, how many words are in a block? What if two matching blocks are full of filler/stop words such as articles, would you really want to consider those? Instead you might consider lexical similarity to determine how alike are two texts.

This is not quite what you asked for, but you can use the {stringdist} package to evaluate the "distance" between two texts, generally interpreted as the amount of characters that you would have to modify in a string in order to become equal to the reference string. So "friend" and "friendly" would have a difference of 2.
This way you could check which texts have less differences compared to the reference text, possibly meaning that they were copied straight away from the source material.
# https://github.com/markvanderloo/stringdist
install.packages('stringdist')

library(stringdist)

base_text <- "she grew up in the united states.Her father was"

text_1 <- "She grew up in the United States. Her father was"
text_2 <- "I learned that she grew up in the united states.Her father was"
text_3 <- "The main character was born in the USA, his father being"
text_4 <- "My favourite animals are raccoons, they are so silly and cute"
text_5 <- "I didn't understand this assignment so I'm just answering gibberish"
text_6 <- "she grew up in the united states.Her father was"

test_texts <- c(text_1, text_2, text_3, text_4, text_5, text_6)

# calculate string distance using default method
distances <- stringdist(base_text, test_texts)

# texts that are only x or less edits away from the original text
possible_copied_texts <- test_texts[distances <= 25]

possible_copied_texts

#[1] "She grew up in the United States. Her father was"              
#[2] "I learned that she grew up in the united states.Her father was"
#[3] "she grew up in the united states.Her father was"        

If this method does not work for your use case, you can use stringdist with the The longest common substring method (method='lcs'), which is defined as the "longest string that can be obtained by pairing characters from an and b while keeping the order of characters intact." This way we can find if longer texts have a pasted text inside them, even if it is slightly modified:
library(stringdist)

base_text_2 <- "this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur"

text_7 <- "random string with no words from the base text"
text_8 <- "cat dog pig chicken duck this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur food pizza sandwich pineapple"
text_9 <- "this pretty long sentence does in fact mean that I have not plagiarized any text, instead I'm writing all by myself"
text_10 <- "what so you mean you are doubting this text? you can't actually think that this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur, even if it does use words straight from the plagiarism sentence"
text_11 <- "totally normal text"
text_12 <- "this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur"
text_13 <- "this sentence does not mean plagiarism and therefore something bad not will occur"
# here, strings 8, 10, and 12 contain the base text in them, and string 13 contains a slightly modified version of the base text which would still be plagiarism

# create a vector with the strings
test_texts_2 <- c(text_7, 
                  text_8, 
                  text_9, 
                  text_10,
                  text_11,
                  text_12,
                  text_13)

# but we will also add filler text before and after every string, so that they become longer
filler <- "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"
test_texts_3 <- paste(filler, test_texts_2, filler)

# perform strins distance calculation with the  longest common substring method
distances_lcs <- stringdist(base_text_2, test_texts_3, method = "lcs")

# we get the distances substrazcted from the length of every string, then we substract the lenght of the base text so that strings with the base text become zero
distance_lcs_results <- nchar(test_texts_3) - distances_lcs - nchar(base_text_2)

# strings with a value of 0 means the exact text is present in the text
distance_lcs_results
#> [1] -38   0 -24   0 -44   0  -2

# subset the vector so that we can confirm that the strings that contain the text were detected
test_texts_2[distance_lcs_results == 0]
#> [1] "cat dog pig chicken duck this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur food pizza sandwich pineapple"                                                                                     
#> [2] "what so you mean you are doubting this text? you can't actually think that this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur, even if it does use words straight from the plagiarism sentence"
#> [3] "this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur"

# but we can also get close matches, strings containing text that are not the same, but similar, to the base texts
test_texts_2[abs(distance_lcs_results) < 20]
#> [1] "cat dog pig chicken duck this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur food pizza sandwich pineapple"                                                                                     
#> [2] "what so you mean you are doubting this text? you can't actually think that this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur, even if it does use words straight from the plagiarism sentence"
#> [3] "this sentence means plagiarism therefore something bad will occur"                                                                                                                                            
#> [4] "this sentence does not mean plagiarism and therefore something bad not will occur"

You could use both methods (or more!) to create a score variable, and then make a decision based on multiple plagiarism metrics.
Created on 2024-07-24 with reprex v2.1.0

This could work in some contexts, but I'm not sure it would work well in the context of a long work where, for instance, 1000 words might be distinct but a 100-word paragraph might be copied verbatim.

That is true, but upon reading about the many methods for distance calculation, I found about this one: "The longest common substring (method='lcs') is defined as the longest string that can be obtained by pairing characters from a and b while keeping the order of characters intact.". That method might work for the use case you mention (small copy-paste inside a longer text).

Thanks so much!  This is a clever solution. What you provided here is what I was looking for, because students did not always copy and paste the entire portion of text and that order of words matters. What I need to figure out next (and I may come back here for help) is to do this quickly for 90 parent passages and enter the results in a column in a dataframe, as in, 0 and 1 for not plagiarism versus plagiarism. Thank you again!

Happy to help! I believe you can just slap stringdist(column1, column2, method = "lcs") in mutate() on a dataframe where column1 is the original text and column2 are what students wrote, and further calculations can be done on a separate mutate call to get the final numeric values on plagiarism.

Using the data from @Bastián Olea Herrera:
library(tm)
library(slam)

text <- list("she grew up in the united states.Her father was",
             "She grew up in the United States. Her father was",
             "I learned that she grew up in the united states.Her father was",
             "The main character was born in the USA, his father being",
             "My favourite animals are raccoons, they are so silly and cute",
             "I didn't understand this assignment so I'm just answering gibberish",
             "she grew up in the united states.Her father was"
)

tdm <- VectorSource(sapply(text, \(x) gsub(".", " ", x, fixed = T), USE.NAMES = F)) |>
  SimpleCorpus() |>
  TermDocumentMatrix(
    control = list(tolower = TRUE,
                   removePunctuation = TRUE,
                   stopwords = TRUE))

cs <-  crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(tdm)/(sqrt(col_sums(tdm^2) %*% t(col_sums(tdm^2))))
cs
#     Docs
# Docs         1         2         3         4 5 6         7
#    1 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8944272 0.2236068 0 0 1.0000000
#    2 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8944272 0.2236068 0 0 1.0000000
#    3 0.8944272 0.8944272 1.0000000 0.2000000 0 0 0.8944272
#    4 0.2236068 0.2236068 0.2000000 1.0000000 0 0 0.2236068
#    5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1 0 0.0000000
#    6 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 1 0.0000000
#    7 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8944272 0.2236068 0 0 1.0000000

This is just an example that you could build on -- tm has a lot more functionality. The idea here is you can build a term document matrix and use that to compute a similarity score between documents. The similarity score computed here is cosine similarity but there are many others.
If you read the documentation for ?TermDocumentMatrix you can see you can do things like inverse weighting procedures, which gives more weight to uncommon words, for example.
The first column of the output compares the first text to all the text, the second column compares the second text to all the text and so forth. The diagonal is always one because it is comparing the text to itself. As you can see from the first column, the second, third and seventh text are all pretty similar to the first.

Alternatively, you can extract the longest common substring like so (using the text list from above). This compares the first element (your base text/digital assignment) to the remaining text (this should be student input):
library(PTXQC)
library(textclean)

standardize <- function(x) {
  x |>
    tolower() |>
    replace_contraction() |> 
    gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", x = _, perl = T) |>
    replace_white()
}

std_text <- standardize(text)

lapply(std_text[-1], \(x) LCSn(c(std_text[[1]], x)))
# [[1]]
# [1] "she grew up in the united states her father was"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "she grew up in the united states her father was"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] " in the u"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] " the"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] " un"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "she grew up in the united states her father was"

First, a little text cleaning is done to standardize the text. I add space around punctuation to address that issue in your text_2. This may introduce excess white space, but that is resolved with replace_white().
LCSn() has a min_LCS_length you can specify to ignore minimally overlapping text.
Note: PTXQC and textclean have a fair number of dependencies.

Will this identify if 100 words are verbatim but 1000 other words are different? Does it identify if the words are in the same order or just working from the same vocabulary?

@JonSpring thanks these are good questions to clarify for the OP. First, no. This specific example, which is just meant to be a working example, would not. It considers all words in a term document matrix so order does not matter in this code, which should answer your second question. That being said there are tools to aid with these situations that I leave up to the OP to research and decide on. For example, you don't have to tokenize by word. The control argument allows for other tokenization methods.

Second, they could compute other similarity metrics to account for the 100 words exact, 1000 distinct words example you mention. @Bastián Olea Herrera mentions a good one for that scenario -- the longest common substring. I used cosine similarity here since it is a very common method for determining text similarity.

Thank you so much for your contribution.  This approach is really cool and something for me to think about for my future endeavors with text analysis.  I imagine that in many cases, calculating cosine similarities between texts based on vocabularies, regardless of the order, may be good enough.  In my case, I was also looking to see that the order of words is preserved, but I will look into the documentation you provided to learn more.  Thanks again!

Here's an approach to identify contiguous words in common using tidytext, looking for verbatim copying of phrases. Here, I strip out punctuation (at least .,;?!) and make n-grams (phrases of length n) to match between two sources.
In this case I look for contiguous phrases of 7-10 words. For large data, a large range could become computationally- and memory-intensive. A small phrase length will capture more false positives from common phrases, while a long phrase length could lead to false negatives (not catching plagiarism, so this will take some adjusting for the context.
library(tidyverse); library(tidytext)
tokenize <- function(str_vec, from = 7, to = 10) {
  data.frame(text = str_vec) |>
    mutate(text = text |> 
             str_replace_all("[.,;?!] ", " ") |>
             str_replace_all("[.,;?!]",  " ")) |>
    tidytext::unnest_ngrams(phrase, text, n = to, n_min = from,  to_lower = TRUE) |>
    mutate(length = str_count(phrase, "\\w+"))
}

inner_join(
  text_1 |> tokenize() |> mutate(src = "text_1"),
  text_2 |> tokenize() |> mutate(src = "text_2"),
  join_by(phrase, length)
) |>
  arrange(-length)
  

Result
                                            phrase length  src.x  src.y
1  she grew up in the united states her father was     10 text_1 text_2
2      she grew up in the united states her father      9 text_1 text_2
3      grew up in the united states her father was      9 text_1 text_2
4             she grew up in the united states her      8 text_1 text_2
5          grew up in the united states her father      8 text_1 text_2
6           up in the united states her father was      8 text_1 text_2
7                 she grew up in the united states      7 text_1 text_2
8                 grew up in the united states her      7 text_1 text_2
9               up in the united states her father      7 text_1 text_2
10             in the united states her father was      7 text_1 text_2


Another clever solution! I tested it with different versions where I switched the order of words around and it only counted words where order was preserved, which is what I was looking for. But the challenge about this approach is that I would have to identify ahead of time the threshold of contiguous phrases and sometimes it's not clear to me.  Thanks so much.
